# Placing a boundary around a series of points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boundary

I have a series of points that I want to place a boundary around. How can I go about this?

These are my points:
[image]

I tried geom_line but that was obviously wrong since it produced this!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: ...as long as the points are in the correct order.

Comment: @Spacedman, do you have a recommendation for unordered points?  There isn't a `geom_convex_hull`, is there (although the boundary above isn't even convex, which makes it worse)?

Comment: Its pretty much impossible to automate - look at that awkward bit towards the top where there's three sets of points in parallel. Is that an inlet (in which case from which side) or an island or a spiky bit of coastline. My recommendation is to join the dots manually.

Comment: luckily the points are in the right order as I am basically tracing reefs in googlemap as paths...not the most elegant of solutions but hey it works

Comment: If the reefs you are tracing are in google maps imagery then you are most likely violating their terms of use...

Comment: Surely not since it is merely a crude path and google maps themselves allow the export of crude paths

Answer (score 4):

Use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`. Here is an example:

```
i <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=50)
dat <- data.frame(x=cos(i), y=sin(i))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: geom_path doesn't always necessary give nice shape as you have shown.Are there other options to try?